# Como iniciar comunicaçao Serial do Arduino com Raspberry PI 3

Tags: java, github, arduino, raspberry-pi

eu estou fazendo um projetinho no Arduino e preciso iniciar a comunicaçao Serial com a Raspberry PI 3 sem IDE com o S.O Raspbian Lite. Ou seja, o Raspbian Lite nao tem interface grafica pra poder abrir a IDE e iniciar a comunicaçao, quero fazer isso pelo terminal msm.

[Encontrei esse programa aqui](https://github.com/turicas/arduinoMakefile) mas nao entendi muito bem como se instala ou compila.

As perguntas são, como eu compilo o programa do link acima no terminal linux? 
Você conhece outro programa pra fazer essa comunicação Serial além do que eu citei?

Minha distro linux é o Fedora 25.

Comment: No RPi você pode fazer a comunicação com Python pela biblioteca *pyserial*.

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está perguntando afinal. Sua dúvida é acerca do programa que não instala ou compila? Ou você quer explicações sobre a comunicação serial? Se o problema é o programa, que erro ocorreu contigo?